# Linking c++ dlib project to c#

Tags: c#, c++

I have a project "Implementation of cca" using dlib library c++, on the other hand, I have a project which used c#.
Actually, I have no idea how to link them.
Please can you help me

Answer (score 1):

Use the System.Runtime.InteropServices-namespace like described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282.aspx

Good examples are http://www.dotnetperls.com/dllimport or https://drthitirat.wordpress.com/2013/05/30/combine-gui-of-c-with-c-codes/

Comment: Can you explain more to me the idea plz?